# Remove long sub-command help output?

Tags: python, python-2.7, argparse

I'm using [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html) to produce my CLI and using the [`add_subparsers`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.add_subparsers) function. This works exception the `--help` output is really ugly. It lists all the commands in the overall syntax. For example:

```
usage: redid [-h] [--config CONFIG] [--verbose] [--show-curl] [--save [SAVE]]

             {setup,show-config,check-auth,version,get-profile,put-profile,delete-profile,get-profile-signature,list-profiles,list-resources,ls-resources,get-resource-record,delete-resource,get-resource,upload-resource,get-resource-url}
             ...
```

I'd much prefer to have a more traditional and clean output similar to:

```
usage: redid [OPTIONS...] Command ...
```

How can I do this?

Comment: You can pass an [`usage`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#usage) argument to the [`ArgumentClass`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser) constructor...

Comment: @Bakuriu, no, that doesn't work as expected. It leaves the long string in the subcommand help. Additionally this breaks the `--help` feature for the sub-commands (it just appends the subcommand help to this usage string).

Comment: You can pass an [`usage`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#usage) argument to the [`ArgumentParser`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser) constructor... and if you read the documentation about [`add_subparsers`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.add_subparsers) you'll discover that `add_parser` accepts *exactly* the same arguments as [`ArgumentParser`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser).

Comment: It's not the sub-command help that is the problem, but the combined form with the base help. It turns out I can specify a `prog` option to `add_subparsers` which kind of fixes that problem though.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the `metavar` argument to your subparser definition and give it no value:

```
parser.add_subparsers(title="the_commands", metavar="")
```

[From the documentation](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#sub-commands):

> Description of parameters:
>
> ....
>
> - metavar - string presenting available sub-commands in help; by default it is None and presents sub-commands in form {cmd1, cmd2, ..}

Here's an example, I'm not sure how you've set up your sub-parsers but:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='PROG')
parser.add_argument('--foo', action='store_true', help='foo help')
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(help="sub-command help", metavar="sub command")
parser_a = subparsers.add_parser('a', help='a help')
parser_a.add_argument('bar', type=int, help='bar help')
parser_b = subparsers.add_parser('b', help='b help')
parser_b.add_argument('--baz', choices='XYZ', help='baz help')

>>> parser.print_help()
usage: PROG [-h] [--foo] sub command ...

positional arguments:
  sub command  sub-command help
    a          a help
    b          b help

optional arguments:
  -h, --help   show this help message and exit
  --foo        foo help
```

Comment: That drops the string, but now in the general syntax it simply doesn't mention the sub-commands at all.

Comment: If I put some text it displays that. The sub-help also has the annoying text, but at least it's better than the long string.

Comment: This is the only way I've been able to fix a similar problem.

Comment: I replied to Bakuriu for this. It doesn't work as expected. In particular when getting sub-command help it just appends the sub-command help to this string making a confusing output.

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y I've added an example, I'm not sure if it fixes it but take a look.

Comment: This gets me part of the way. Using the `usage` option and also the `prog` option to `add_subparsers` takes it a bit further. It's still not the desired output, but closer.